# Google Closure Compiler advanced: remove code blocks at compile time

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

If I take this code and compile it (advanced optimizations)

```
/**@constructor*/
function MyObject() {
    this.test = 4
    this.toString = function () {return 'test object'}
}
window['MyObject'] = MyObject
```

I get this code

```
window.MyObject=function(){this.test=4;this.toString=function(){return"test object"}};
```

Is there any way I can remove the toString function using the Closure Compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString` is implicitly callable, so unless the Closure compiler can prove that the result of `MyObject` is never coerced to a string it has to preserve it.

You can always mark it as explicit debug code:

```
this.test = 4;
if (goog.DEBUG) {
  this.toString = function () { return "test object"; };
}
```

then in your non-debug build, compile with

```
goog.DEBUG = false;
```

See http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.source.html which does

```
/**
 * @define {boolean} DEBUG is provided as a convenience so that debugging code
 * that should not be included in a production js_binary can be easily stripped
 * by specifying --define goog.DEBUG=false to the JSCompiler. For example, most
 * toString() methods should be declared inside an "if (goog.DEBUG)" conditional
 * because they are generally used for debugging purposes and it is difficult
 * for the JSCompiler to statically determine whether they are used.
 */
goog.DEBUG = true;
```

Comment: I am trying to use this, but how do I specify this to the compiler in http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home ? I tried setting goog.DEBUG-false; but it doesn't work...  :(

Comment: @edbras, you can use the -D flag to closure compiler to set it.  From the help: ` --define (--D, -D) VAL                 : Override the value of a variable annotated @define. The format is <name>[=<val>], where <name> is the name of a @define variable and <val> is a boolean,number, or a single-quoted string that contains no single quotes. If [=<val>] is omitted, the variable is marked true`

Comment: I have the same problem. Trying to make the compiler strip console.log calls with SIMPLE optimization. For me goog.DEBUG does not work in the online service.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is surprising simple. I was researching this and didn't find the correct answer, so I am adding it here. The solution is to use a JSDoc annotation (see https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#const-const-type):

```
/* @const */
const debug = false;
```

Now anywhere in your code (also inside of nested functions) you can do the following:

```
if (debug) console.log("hello world");
```

Or in your case invalidate a complete block

```
if (debug) {
    /* your code to remove */    
}
```

If you set `debug` to false the Closure compiler can remove it because it knows you declared debug a constant a hence it won't change and the code will never be executed if gated with your debug variable.

Comment: yes but you have to change manually the value of the variable everywhere. The correct answer was correct. The only problem is that `-D` option (@define) doesn't work in ES6 modules. I mean, cmon it's 2020 and Google cannot make define in modules. For different build targets, I've written a small script that would patch the value of the variable before proceeding to compilation, that's the only solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `@define` doesn't work in modules, I wrote a patch that can be run before compilation. It goes:

```
import { c } from '@artdeco/erte'
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'

const [,,version] = process.argv

const PATH = join(__dirname, 'index.js')
let f = readFileSync(PATH, 'utf-8')

const isFree = version == '--free'

if (isFree) {
  f = f.replace("\nimport isFree from './paid'", "\n// import isFree from './paid'")
  f = f.replace("\n// import isFree from './free'", "\nimport isFree from './free'")
  console.log('Set version to %s', c('free', 'red'))
} else {
  f = f.replace("\n// import isFree from './paid'", "\nimport isFree from './paid'")
  f = f.replace("\nimport isFree from './free'", "\n// import isFree from './free'")
  console.log('Set version to %s', c('paid', 'magenta'))
}

writeFileSync(PATH, f)
```

Usage:
node ./src/version/patch --free
node ./src/version/patch --paid

And the actual `./src/version/index.js` that's being patched:

```
// import isFree from './free'
import isFree from './paid'
```

With './free':

```
export default true
```

With './paid':

```
export default true
```

And based on that, you can export a variable from `index.js`:

```
export const free = isFree
```

So this was to allow compiling paid and free packages, but you could extend this code to adjust for debug/production version.

Still, this should be done with `-D` (@define) but apparently it's very difficult for a trillion-dollar company that Google is.