# Removing debug code from inside a function using Closure Compiler simple optimisations

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, minify

I'm looking for a way to strip out debug code from functions so I can add test hooks to closures.  I've read
[Google Closure Compiler advanced: remove code blocks at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167519/google-closure-compiler-advanced-remove-code-blocks-at-compile-time) and tested out removing debug code with the following:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var DEBUG = true;

if (DEBUG) {
    console.log('remove me');
}
```

Simple optimisation with `--define='DEBUG=false'` reduces this to `var DEBUG=!1;`.  The same applies for this:

```
/** @const */
var DEBUG = false;

if (DEBUG) {
    console.log('remove me');
}
```

Where I run into trouble is using this convention inside a function:

```
/** @const */
var DEBUG = false;

function logMe() {
    if (DEBUG) {
        console.log('remove me');
    }
}
```

This reduces to the following:

```
var DEBUG=!1;function logMe(){DEBUG&&console.log("remove me")};
```

I would expect it to reduce further to:

```
var DEBUG=!1;function logMe(){};
```

Is there a reason this is not working as expected?  I'm really just looking for a clean way to strip debug code and am not ready to take the plunge into advanced optimizations.

**Update**

Per @John's answer, I implemented my own compiler and have found that the following configuration will remove `if (DEBUG) {}` from inside and outside the code for the case of a `@define`:

```
CompilerOptions options = new CompilerOptions();
CompilationLevel.SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(options);
//options.setInlineConstantVars(true);
options.setInlineVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.ALL);
options.setDefineToBooleanLiteral("DEBUG", false);
```

This works well enough for a single file with the following limitations:

1. This requires `var DEBUG` to be defined in each file, which is bad practice.
2. When combining multiple files, you can only have a single `var DEBUG` or the compiler can't optimize around it.  This could be avoided by compiling each file individually and merging them.
3. Because the value is defined at the beginning of the file, there's no flexibility to receive the value beforehand.

I've toyed with the idea of removing all `var DEBUG` definitions from the files and injecting it into the source or extern before execution, but I've run into two issues:

- Defining it in extern appears to do nothing.
- Undefined `DEBUG` in the uncompiled code throws a reference error in the browser.

The ideal option would be to test `window.DEBUG`, which does not throw a reference error.  Unfortunately, while injecting `/** @const */ var window = {}; /** @const */ window.DEBUG = false;` works at the top level, reducing `if (window.DEBUG) {}`, the optimization is actually reverted if placed in a function.

Unless another compiler option works the only option that would really make sense is to go with `window.DEBUG` and before compilation inject `/** @const */ var DEBUG = false;` and to a global replace of `/\bwindow.DEBUG\b/` with `DEBUG`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Closure Compiler's simple optimizations won't strip out unused code, just minify it.  It's doing the minification correctly - the compiler doesn't know that this variable is an unchanging flag.  You'll need to use the advanced optimizations if you want it to strip out unused code.

Comment: Hi @AlecAnanian, per the first two examples, simple optimizations will remove always-false `if` blocks at the script level.  I'm trying to understand why this approach doesn't work one level down in a function.

Comment: Oh, I see - it looks like you have to use the specific goog.DEBUG flag for the simple optimization to take it into account.

Answer (score 4):

Use @define annotation:

```
@define {boolean}
```

DEBUG = true;

And compile with option

--define="DEBUG=false"

Answer (score 3):

A custom build of the compiler would allow you to do this.  You basically want to "inline constant variables":

options.setInlineConstantVars(true);

You could add it here, in applySafeCompilationOptions:
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java?r=706

Or you could use the Java API and add the option (without modifying the compiler's code). Michael Bolin given an example of how to do this here:

http://blog.bolinfest.com/2009/11/calling-closure-compiler-from-java.html

Comment: Cool.  I'll have to give the API part a shot tomorrow.  I'll eventually want to offload the work to a maven plugin so it'll be reasonable to write a custom compiler runner.

Comment: I've updated above.  It seems that `options.setInlineVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.ALL)` is required.  Unfortunately, there are a lot of caveats and I can only think of a really hackish solution to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old answer, but I found a way that's not mentioned here.

```
(function(){
    var DEBUG = true;

    if (DEBUG) {
        if (something === "wrong") {
            console.warn("Stop!  Hammer time!");
        }
        else if (something === "as expected") {
            console.log("All good :-)");
        }
    }

    foo();
})();
```

With ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS this compiles to this:

```
"wrong" === something ? 
    console.warn("Stop!  Hammer time!") : 
    "as expected" === something && console.log("All good :-)");
foo();
```

In our build script we can rewrite the DEBUG line to set it to `false`, which would then yield this output.

```
foo();
```

---

The reason this happens is Closure will remove unreachable code.  By creating the closure, and defining a local variable, Closure can see that we can't do something like `window.DEBUG === true`, so the code is guaranteed to never be run.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DEBUG` variable is currently global. GCC will not remove or rename global variables in simple optimization mode, so they'll remain available to any code in other scripts that might possibly want to access them. Try enclosing your code into anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved the problem of "removing debug functions from closure compiled javascript using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATION" was by combining a similar method as @John proposes as well as using some of @Brian Nichols update. I could only get the compiler to remove the lines by placing this is the global scope of my main js file and doing a custom compile (using multiple .js files this still removed them)

```
/** @const 
*   @type {boolean}
*/
var DEBUG = false;

//and used this format for my debug function
DEBUG && myLog('foo');
```

and then compiling the closure-compiler java with ant to include this option options.setInlineVariables(CompilerOptions.Reach.ALL);
 under the applySafeCompilationOptions function in the CompilationLevel.java file as @john suggests. This worked for me and didnt break my codebase as ADVANCED did...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var DEBUG = true;` from your code and convert all your conditions that check `if (DEBUG)` to `if (goog.DEBUG)`.  Modify your compiler option to read `--define goog.DEBUG=false`.  The `goog` variable is built into the Closure Library API to provide options and flags for the compiler.

Comment: I gave it a try and got this warning: `WARNING - unknown @define variable goog.DEBUG`.  The code didn't get stripped.

Comment: For the record, I executed `java -jar compiler.jar --js=test.js -D goog.DEBUG=false` with compiler.jar version 20120430.

Comment: This will require you to include the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library).  If you're not using it, advanced optimizations settings for the compiler is the way to go.

Comment: I went through the process and it works, *but* I really wanted to avoid the advanced optimizations and bringing in a new library.  It's a really high price to pay for suppressing a block of code.

Comment: That said, it is really cool how the builder and compiler can take a huge library and distill it down to the handful of components needed for execution.

Comment: Hmm... It looks like `goog.DEBUG` isn't magical either.  It only works because of the Closure Library so there's no actual need to include it for this task.